# Odoo Search Domain Filter with multiple values

Tags: search, filter, odoo

i have row like below Structure:

```
 Product  UOM    Barcode_one Barcode_Two Barcode_three Barcode_four price

 Orange   unit      123       456         789          457      23
 Orange   dozen                            378                  210
 orange   pack      222       29437                             200
 apple    unit      345                                         60
```

when i search the barcode  with  barcode like   378  it will display only one row ..

```
 Orange dozen    378
```

i want to display all the 3 rows .. with any barcode ..

My XML

```
 <search string="Search Product by Barcode">
        <field name="name" string="Barcode"
            filter_domain="['|','|','|', 
              ('barcode_one','ilike',self),
              ('barcode_two','ilike',self), 
              ('barcode_three', 'ilike', self),
              ('barcode_four', 'ilike', self),                
              ]"/>
            <field name="related_categ_id"/> 
            <field name="related_type"/>    
            <field name="related_group_id"/>                        
        </search>
```

MY select Query like :

```
Select * from product_pricelist_item 
where 
barcode_one ilike '29437' 
or barcode_two ilike '29437' 
or barcode_three ilike '29437' 
or barcode_four ilike '29437' 
or product_tmpl_id in ( Select product_tmpl_id from                              
product_pricelist_item  where 
barcode_one ilike '29437' 
or barcode_two ilike '29437' 
or barcode_three ilike '29437' 
or barcode_four ilike '29437')
```

How to resolve it ?

Comment: do you want to search barcode value in all four rows when user search for barcode right?

Comment: yes, if user has enter any barcode like "222" i want to display all UOM prices... w.r.t product

Answer (score 1):

**name_search** will do a job for you in odoo to extend the search result.

Here is a basic name_search method you can modify according to your need in your model.

```
def name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    if not args:
        args = []
    if name:
        args += ['|', '|', '|', ("barcode_one", operator, name), ("barcode_two", operator, name), ("barcode_three", operator, name), ("barcode_four", operator, name)]
    return super(Product, self).name_search(name, args=args, operator=operator, limit=limit)
```

kindly change the field name in the search args according to your field in the model.

hope this helps!

Comment: name_search call when used in "many2one". My customization in TreeView Search

Comment: I can acheve this by product_all_barcode = fields.Char(
             'All Barcode',
             compute=_compute_barcodes_code, search='_search_barcode_product'
    )

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this filter :

> filter_domain="[(self, 'in', ['barcode_one',
>   'barcode_two','barcode_three','barcode_four'])]"

Comment: ValueError: Invalid field u'14107B1FE4' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: (u'14107B1FE4', u'in', [u'barcode_one', u'barcode_two', u'barcode_three', u'barcode_four']) on product_pricelist_item (ctx: )>"